# MANOVA shows no significance but univariables have large differences

Tags: t-test, manova

I conducted a MANOVA with 3 dependents and 1 independent (with only 2 groups). The MANOVA test shows no significance. But the average value over the 3 dependents are very different for the two groups. I am wondering if this possible? I think normally, if MANOVA shows no significance, the average value of the 3 dependents will be close for the two groups.

Do I misunderstand the MANOVA? Since there are only 2 groups, should I use a multivarate t-test instead of MANOVA?

Answer (score 0):

Significance testing doesn't tell you how "large" differences are, per se. In fact, significance is driven by 3 things: size of the difference, sample size, and variability. Thus, if you have a very small sample size and/or a very large amount of variability, even large mean differences may be statistically nonsignificant.